# Laravel Eloquent how to override the base query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, overriding, query-builder

I have 2 models shared a same table.

Table name: **books**, I separate normal book & novel by an attribute called `type`

**Book** model

```
class Book extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'books';
}
```

**Novel** model

```
class Novel extends Book
{
    protected $table = 'books';

    // Is such a method available?
    protected function someMethodToOverride()
    {
        $this->where('type', 'novel');
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve here is

```
$results = Novel::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $title . '%')->get();
```

from this query, I want it to pre-set the condition

```
where('type', 'novel')
```

Is there any function I can override to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Anonymous Global Scopes and add this  boot method in `Novel` Model

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('type', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', 'novel');
        });
    }
```

now it will automatically add query

```
$results = Novel::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $title . '%')->get();
```

> now If you would like to remove a global scope for a given query, you
>   may use the  `withoutGlobalScope` method.

```
Novel::withoutGlobalScope('type')->get();
```

for more information read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes)

Comment: Wow~ Exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Model You can use scope:

```
public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->where('type', $type);
}
```

And pass the parameters when calling the scope:

```
 Model::ofType('novel')
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $title . '%')
        ->get();
```

refer link [Laravel Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)